# My Custom HTML block, running a custom JS script, in footer of Wordpress site has suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, html

hope this finds you well!

I'm not the greatest with HTML and JS, so apologies if there's something really simple I'm overlooking! So I don't need to print my email address in HTML, I used a simple JavaScript script I found somewhere on this site.

This worked well for weeks with no issues, but seemingly overnight it has stopped working. As far as I know, I haven't made any changes that should affect this. I hadn't changed anything in the footer or footer settings. I'm still able to see the HTML trying to run the script in 'view-source', and I can see the object itself in 'Inspect' - the <p> section is fully visible (albeit with no contents), but the <script> section seems to have no attributes/dimensions (if that makes sense!) I even tried adding custom color and visibility to the class through CSS in a last-ditch effort, but that didn't help either.

Here's the code:

```
function gen_mail_to_link(lhs,rhs,subject) {
    document.write("<a class=\"email\" href=\"mailto");
    document.write(":" + lhs + "@");
    document.write(rhs + "?subject=" + subject + "\">" + lhs + "@" + rhs + "<\/a>");
}
```

This is displayed in the site's footer using a Custom HTML block in Wordpress:

```
<p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        gen_mail_to_link('me','fakeemail.com','Enquiry');
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <em>Enable JavaScript to see email address</em>
    </noscript>
</p>
```

Hope someone can make some sense out of any of this! If anyone is able to point me in the right direction I'd be very appreciative. Many thanks :)

Comment: There is no apparant reason why this shouldn't work. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to examine. Is your browser console printing any errors?

Comment: At the very least, you'll want to stop using `document.write`, it's not 1998 anymore. Also, you don't indicate the `type` for a script tag unless your code _isn't_ JS, so you probably want to spend a little time on getting the modern equivalent of that highly out of date JS.